# Collection was mutated while being enumerated - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

In my SwiftUI project I'm fetching data from API and storing in Core Data. However i'm facing crashes with error `Thread 2: "*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x6000023bc270> was mutated while being enumerated."`
Can't seem to find the issue and how to fix it.

I had checked the Core Data option while creating the project, so the setup for Core Data was already there.

Core Data Entity
[image]

On View:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
// And on onAppear, fetching the data
.onAppear {
   viewModel.fetchCurrencies()
}
```

And the logic (ViewModel and DataManagers):

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

actor DataManager {
    private var apiManager = APIManager.shared
    private var coreDataManager = CoreDataManager.shared
    
    func fetchCurrencies() async throws -> [Currency] {
        let lastFetchDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "LastFetchDate") as? Date ?? Date.distantPast
        
//      Check if 30 minutes have passed since the last fetch
        if Date().timeIntervalSince(lastFetchDate) >= 30 * 60 {
            debugPrint("Fetching from API")
            let currencies = try await apiManager.fetchCurrencies()
            coreDataManager.saveCurrencies(currencies)

            let currenciesRates = try await apiManager.fetchCurrenciesRates()
            coreDataManager.saveCurrencyRates(currenciesRates)

            // Update the last fetch timestamp in UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "LastFetchDate")
            return currencies
        } else {
            debugPrint("Fetching from Core Data")
            return try await coreDataManager.fetchCurrencies()
        }
    }
}

// CurrencyResponse.swift
struct CurrencyResponse: Codable {
    let rates: [String: Double]
}

// Currency.swift
struct Currency: Codable, Hashable {
    let code: String
    let name: String
    let rate: Double
}

// CoreDataManager.swift
class CoreDataManager {
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    private init() {}
    
    private var context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    
    // Implement methods to fetch and save currencies to Core Data.
    func fetchCurrencies() async throws -> [Currency] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<CurrencyEntity> = CurrencyEntity.fetchRequest()
        let currencyEntities = try context.fetch(request)
        return currencyEntities.map { Currency(code: $0.code!, name: $0.name!, rate: $0.rate) }
    }
    
    // Clear Entities
    func deleteAllCurrencies() {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = CurrencyEntity.fetchRequest()
        let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

        do {
            try context.execute(batchDeleteRequest)
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error deleting currencies: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func saveCurrencies(_ currencies: [Currency]) {
        
        for currency in currencies {
            if let currencyEntity = getCurrencyEntityByCode(code: currency.code, context: context) {
                currencyEntity.rate = currency.rate
                currencyEntity.name = currency.name
            } else {
                let currencyEntity = CurrencyEntity(context: context)
                currencyEntity.code = currency.code
                currencyEntity.name = currency.name
            }
        }
        
        saveContext()
    }
    
    func saveCurrencyRates(_ currencies: [Currency]) {
        for currency in currencies {
            let currencyEntity = getCurrencyEntityByCode(code: currency.code, context: context)
            currencyEntity?.rate = currency.rate
        }
        
        saveContext()
    }
    
    func getCurrencyEntityByCode(code: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> CurrencyEntity? {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CurrencyEntity> = CurrencyEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "code == %@", code)

        do {
            let currencies = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return currencies.first
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching currency: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    private func saveContext() {
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Error saving context: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

// APIManager.swift
class APIManager {
    static let shared = APIManager()
    private init() {}
    
    private var appID: String {
        let value = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "OPEN_EXCHANGE_APPID") as? String
        guard let value = value else {
            debugPrint("AppID is not set")
            return ""
        }
        return value
    }
    
    private let baseURL = "https://openexchangerates.org/"
    
    func fetchCurrencies() async throws -> [Currency] {
        guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + "/api/currencies.json?" + "&app_id=" + appID) else { return [] }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        let fetchedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: String].self, from: data)
        var currencies: [Currency] = []
        for (code, name) in fetchedData {
            currencies.append(Currency(code: code, name: name, rate: 0.0))
        }
        return currencies
    }
    
    func fetchCurrenciesRates() async throws -> [Currency] {
        guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + "/api/latest.json?" + "&app_id=" + appID) else { return [] }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        let fetchedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CurrencyResponse.self, from: data)
        var currencies: [Currency] = []
        for (code, rate) in fetchedData.rates {
            currencies.append(Currency(code: code, name: "", rate: rate))
        }
        return currencies
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017